# how to get right alignment of text in multi-column section?

Tags: overleaf

I have written the latex code as:

```
\multicolumn{15}{|c|}{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}{\textbf{Total = 4.5767}}\\
```

but I am getting the error as follow:

Undefined control sequence.
@sharp ->\RaggedRight \arraybackslash

How do resolve it?

Comment: Use \multicolumn{15}{|r|}{\textbf{Total... }} instead.

Comment: thank you very much